# Software to visually diagram out 2D rectangles, triangles, and angles, and mainpulate them on a plane

Tags: diagram, graphic-design, vector-graphics, design

I have found myself drawing lots of rectangles and triangles for my home bay windows renovation. I want to be able to place rectangle and triangles on a 2D plane, and also be able to manually input side lengths and have angles displayed.

While I understand there are CAD software that does this, I am hoping for a simple minimal interface that does not have too steep a learning curve. Web based would be ok.